# Actual argument int cannot be converted to byte by method invocation conversion

Tags: java, byte

```
if (Class51.aBoolean5331) {
  int i_11_ = -1;
  if ((Class174.clientCycle % 30 ^ 0xFFFFFFFF) < -16) {
    i_11_ = 16777215;
  }
  byte b = -118;
  graphicstoolkit.method1243(12, i_2_ + 350 - Class262_Sub15_Sub1.aClass357_10524.anInt4442 + -11, i_11_, Class262_Sub15_Sub1.aClass357_10524.method4033(-6, "--> " + Class188_Sub2_Sub2.method1914(Node_Sub10.aString7081, b).substring(0, Class315.anInt4034)) + 10 + i_1_, 2);
}
```

That's my current code and when I compile it's giving me this error:

Actual argument int cannot be converted to byte by method invocation conversion

Comment: That's one scary looking code...

Comment: It seems likely that this class was not written by hand.

Comment: @LouisWasserman De-obfuscated & decompiled code. That's why it's scary.

Comment: have you logged the `int` value to check if its in the [Java `Byte` range](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Actual argument int cannot be converted to byte by method invocation conversion".

What this means is that you are passing an int into a method that requires a byte. If you have a method like this -

```
public void doSomething(byte b) { }
```

and you call it like this -

```
doSomething(35); // error.
```

it will give a compile time error, because the literal 35 is an int and not a byte. An int cannot be converted to a byte by passing it as a method argument. That's what your error is. Somewhere in your code, a method is accepting a byte, but you are passing an int to it.

Please see this as well - http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/expressions.doc.html